# how to remove surrounding empty data from 3d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with shape (136, 512, 512) this array contains 0s and 1s indicating an objects shape inside this 3d space. I am trying to reduce the size of my array by removing empty slices of the array. essentially I want to keep all the 1s in my array but remove unnecessary rows and columns while keeping my array rectangular, similar to a hitbox or something like that. for example:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

0, 0, 0, 1, 0,

0, 1, 1, 1, 0,

0, 1, 0, 1, 0,

1, 1, 0, 1, 0,

1, 0, 0, 1, 0,

0, 1, 1, 1, 0,

0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

would become:

```
(0, 0, 0, 1,

0, 1, 1, 1,

0, 1, 0, 1,

1, 1, 0, 1,

1, 0, 0, 1,

0, 1, 1, 1)
```

but on a 3d scale

(sorry about the horrible formatting, I'm terrible at this.)

and this is only necessary because pyplot doesn't seem to be able to plot such a large 3d graph with voxels, or atleast takes a very long time on my computer. so if anyone knows how to do large scale 3d plots that would be great.

EDIT
to clarify, the example is only a 2d example but to do this in 3d it must take into account all other rows / cols as each square must be the same shape. Not sure if this makes much sense, its hard to explain it in this many dimensions.

think of it as removing anything outside of the outer most 1s on each side from the centre of the cube.

Comment: Would this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917328/numpy-trim-zeros-in-2d-or-3d

Comment: Looks like you want to take a slice, `arr[1:-1, 0:-1]` omitting the last column and the first and last rows.

Comment: I added [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65547931/1609514) which I think does what you want over on the other SO question linked to above which is pretty much a duplicate.

Comment: @mandulaj yes, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: For removing only the surrounding brackets, read the [excellent answer by Bill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65547931/8491642).

---

You can use [`np.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) and [`np.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) to achieve this.

```py
import numpy as np

l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

arr = np.array(l)
arr1 = np.delete(arr, np.all(arr[..., :] == 0, axis=0), axis=1) # Deletes all 0-value columns
arr2 = np.delete(arr1, np.all(arr1[..., :] == 0, axis=1), axis=0) # Deletes all 0-value rows

print(arr)
print(arr2)
```

*Output*

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
[[0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 0 1]
 [1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1]]
```

The same can be extended to 3D array too.

Comment: OP said that he wants "to keep all the 1s in my array but remove unnecessary rows and columns while keeping my array rectangular". But let me add it for that case too, in case OP wants that.

Comment: I think they only want to remove outer ('surrounding') zeros.  I think this method would remove all zero rows/columns?

Comment: Will this work in a 3D context for my problem (see edit). let me know if the edit doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: @Bill yes I think you understand.