# Resize 3D Numpy array increasing the ROI (Region of Interest)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array that contains my ROI, obtained by peforming a logic and between the CT image and the mask.

[Plot of the ROI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cKY7.jpg)

After performing this operation and a zoom using scipy.ndimage.zoom in order to obtain a volume of 160x160x160, I would like to enlarge the ROI, since right now the amount of values different from 0 is around 5%, or at least remove a lot of 0s (for instance by reducing the volume to 80x80x80 around my ROI)

Do you have any advice?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for my problem.
A user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917328/numpy-trim-zeros-in-2d-or-3d) posted a code that is useful to trim all the 0s from a given n-dimensional array in input.
Then, i used [scipy.ndimage.zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html) to enlarge the volume.

This series of steps allowed me to have a smaller volume with a larger ROI.