# How to discard the upper and lower triangular part of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which represents image data, that I made like this

```
import numpy as np 

array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

My image data has a structure similar (albeit not exactly) to the structure above (i.e most of the values are within the main diagonal and 0's in the upper and lower entries. I would like to get rid of the 0's using a consistent (or constant and not a dynamic) method across all the images in my data so that they all maintain the same shape.

For example, the current solution I can think of is just indexing the array like so

```
array[1:, 3:-3]
```

and the same indices will be applied to all the images in my data to ensure that they all have the same shape. I also looked at numpy's triu and tril's methods but i'm not too sure how to apply it here.

Finally, I also included an image of what I am trying to achieve (that is, getting rid of the zeros below the red line to the left, and the zeros above the red line to the right, in a consistent manner.)

[image: Possible Solution]

Comment: Are the red lines supposed to be diagonal? Your array is not square.

Comment: Is the solution allowed to change the shape of the image? Because numpy arrays need to be rectangular, getting rid of all zeros above or below the main diagonal would require the image to be scewed.

Comment: @Bill ohh I'll have to apologise to everyone. I forgot that upper and lower triangular are concepts related to square matrices. I guess maybe I need to rethink the question? But to answer yours, yes the red lines are meant to be diagonal, but I guess shifted to the right and left of the main diagonal.

Comment: @The_spider yes that is fine.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "discard" and "get rid of" the zeros? Do you mean "avoid storing in memory"?

Comment: @Bill I was just trying to include this in the question actually,  "I think there might be a little bit of a confusion in my question, I'll try to clarify by saying I want to only keep the values within the diagonals (so my new array (in the image I included) would have shape (9, 6) because I'll discard/throw away the 0s to the left of the lower diagonal and the 0s to the right of the upper diagonal).

Comment: I am essentially trying to reduce the number of columns in my image, and I want to keep the columns where the values are non-zero and remove the columns which are mostly zeros. I observe that pretty much all the images have values in diagonal entries, so i'm trying to use this fact to come up with a solution. I understand this would reshape the image and I am okay with that.

Comment: One of the scipy sparse formats stores the diagonals as a rectangular array.  Imagine padding the rows between your diagonals, and stacking them.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be close to what you are asking for:

```
# Note: had to pad the original array to make it 1 column wider
array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

n = array.shape[0]

# Make a regular mesh grid of the size you want to keep
cols, rows = np.meshgrid(np.arange(6), np.arange(n))

# Shift the column indices over to capture the diagonals
cols = cols + np.arange(n).reshape(-1, 1)

# Extract the values you want in a new array
new_array = array[(rows, cols)]
print(new_array)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 5 6 7 0]
 [0 0 9 8 8 0]
 [0 4 9 9 0 0]
 [0 6 5 8 0 0]
 [6 7 0 0 0 0]
 [9 6 0 0 0 0]
 [5 6 7 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

It takes the main diagonal starting from top-left and the 5 elements to the right of the diagonal.

Comment: this ishard coded. in case you have an image covering more than 6 columns, this would truncate the image. OP interested in applying the same indices to all the images. meaning, you must find the image covering the largest portion and use the indices of that.

Comment: @Onyambu if OP wants that it wouldn't be difficult to do. Just reshape the image as above but using the greatest possible width then use a modified version of this [`trim_zeros`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65547931/1609514) method that records the amount trimmed off each extremity.

Comment: The greatest possible width is not known. you have to determine it.

Comment: The image can’t be wider than the array it is stored in.  So that sets an upper limit on the width of the final array.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you might want to check sparse matrix [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLPVJ.png). It provides consistent compression removing zeroes.

An example row sparse matrix representation would be as follows:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# plot
plt.imshow(array)
```

[image]

```
sparse_array = csr_matrix(array)
print(sparse_array)
# discards zero entries
(1, 3)  5
(1, 4)  6
(1, 5)  7
(2, 4)  9
(2, 5)  8
...
(7, 9)  7
```

## it is also easy to plot it:

plt.imshow(sparse_array.toarray())

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLPVJ.png) Compressed Sparse Row matrix: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

Comment: But the sparse matrices are still rectangular in shape, even if the data is only a few diagaonals.  And there isn't a direct way to display them as images.

Comment: @hpaulj I think rectangular shape is OK (see accepted answer), it is also easy to plot.